# Fatal Error while integrating Firestore in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am encountering an issue while integrating firestore to my android studio project but when I pressed the "Add" buttn to push my changes into firestore. I am getting below error:

```
01/11 12:07:05: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5X API 29 x86.
Install successfully finished in 2 s 590 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.do_i_need_it/com.example.do_i_need_it.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 30760 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/le.do_i_need_i: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
E/le.do_i_need_i: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
W/le.do_i_need_i: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( AGjRfZa9HCZCPfxYsG3E6k6zMMu2 ).
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:231): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7005 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.do_i_need_it
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
I/le.do_i_need_i: Background concurrent copying GC freed 16663(7119KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(120KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1836KB/3672KB, paused 506us total 112.513ms
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd993f1e0, tid 30797
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd991a240: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd991a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd990f0b0)
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd993f320, tid 30797
    HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff805000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd991a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd990f0b0)
I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@71e031d
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( AGjRfZa9HCZCPfxYsG3E6k6zMMu2 ).
D/Login Account: signInWithEmail:success
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c4749b6
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd991a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd990f0b0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd991a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd990f0b0)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd991a240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd990f0b0)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeInt(JIZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekInt(JZ)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayIndexScale(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/le.do_i_need_i: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty: uid=10133(com.example.do_i_need_it) AsyncTask #1 identical 2 lines
I/le.do_i_need_i: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryPathElements:[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->makePathElements(Ljava/util/List;)[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
V/NativeCrypto: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/le.do_i_need_i: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 13026(940KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(104KB) LOS objects, 18% free, 2979KB/3665KB, paused 3.950ms total 132.783ms
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WriteStream]: (834a3ea) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:446)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:555)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    }.
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WriteStream]: (834a3ea) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:446)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:555)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    }.
W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WriteStream]: (834a3ea) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:446)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:555)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    }.
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WriteStream]: (834a3ea) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:446)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:555)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    }.
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WriteStream]: (834a3ea) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:446)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:555)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    }.
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WriteStream]: (834a3ea) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:446)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:555)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    }.
W/le.do_i_need_i: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/Firestore: (22.0.0) [WriteStream]: (834a3ea) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:446)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:285)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:555)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    }.
```

I have checked the device has internet connectivity and able to access to Internet, also, it work fine on the Firebase Authentication.
My code:

```
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Map<String,Object> products = new HashMap<>();
        products.put("title",productTitle);
        products.put("price",productPrice);
        products.put("webpage",productWebPage);
        products.put("userId","asa");
        db.collection("products").add(products).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Toast.makeText(c,"Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(c,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

*Currently, I have Firebase Authentication integrated in my environment (which is working fine at the moment).

I have checked with Firebase documentation and follow those guidelines accordingly but the problem still persisted.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) documentation? If yes, which of the mentioned two options have you tried to connect your Android app to Firebase? Does you project meet the listed requirements?

Comment: I have crossed checked all criteria but no luck to make it success.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug a code or make a log to show what happed with your code.